Why is inverse of a transfer function not really a correct way to think while doing circuit analysis?
When we try to predict the circuit behaviour using transfer function, everything works fine in forward direction (Vin to Vout).
But if we try to predict the circuit behaviour in reverse direction (Vout to Vin) assuming the transfer function would be inverse of the forward direction, why do we fail miserably?
I get it practically, but why the inverse is not valid theoretically? Is it because the assumptions involved while deriving forward Transfer function (say, no output loading) is not valid when Vin, Vout terminals change?
Eg1: LC low pass filter

The inverse transfer function predicts the high frequency components will be amplified, which is not the case!
But if I remove C, it becomes bidirectionally valid.
Eg2: Simple resistive voltage divider

To get the inverse transfer function, you must reverse the direction of time.

Would you expect a resistive attenuator to magically amplify in the reverse direction and break the laws of physics? Transfer functions only take into account the signal levels between input and output and pay no attention to input and output impedances. Impedances are the deal breaker.

Would you expect a resistive attenuator to magically amplify in the reverse direction and break the laws of physics? LoL

If you swap input and output terminals, that is a different circuit. Swapping input and output means you need to find the transfer function of that circuit based on which impedances are in series and parallel, and swapping of inputs and outputs is not same as taking the inverse of transfer function.
But if you remove the capacitor, your RL circuit is now symmetric, it will have the same trasfer function in both ways.

Well, assuming that you load the circuit we can see that in the opposite direction the circuit will become:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Which will have a transfer function that looks like:
$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{o}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}}{\displaystyle\text{R}+\text{R}_1+\text{sL}}\tag1$$
